# Getting back updated object mlab api PUT

Tags: ajax, put, mlab

I am trying to modify object using mlab api through ajax call.Following is the code used:

```
query="{'email':'"+localStorage.getItem("email") +"','restore':'yes'}"
object={"$set":{'restore':"no"}}
$.ajax({

url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/coll?apiKey=apiKey&q="+query,
data: JSON.stringify( object ),
type: "PUT",

contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function( restored_obj ) {
console.log(restored_obj)
})
```

The object gets successfully updated.The response that I receive is only the number of objects that are modified and not the modified object itself.
How do I get modified objects without making a round trip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PUT request to the mLab Data API will run MongoDB's `update` command. The `update` command cannot return the updated object ([see the documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)).

But you can run MongoDB's `findAndModify` command by posting to the `/databases/<dbname>/runCommand` endpoint of the mLab Data API. [See the documentation for the `runCommand` endpoint here](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#commands).

`findAndModify` is able to return updated objects. [See the documentation here](http://%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/). If you set the `new` option to `true`, you will receive the newly updated document rather than the old document.

Your code should look something like this:

```
query = {
    email: localStorage.getItem("email"),
    restore: 'yes'
}

object = {
    findAndModify: '<collection>' // use your own collection name
    query: query,
    update: {
        $set: {
            restore: "no"
        }
    },
    new: true
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/runCommand?apiKey=apiKey",
    data: JSON.stringify(object),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function(restored_obj) {
    console.log(restored_obj)
})
```

Also, if you ever want to make an update to a single document by `_id`, the default behavior is that the updated document will be returned. See [the documentation for updating single documents here](http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#view-edit-delete-document).